# Amplitude and phase shift of a periodic function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am stuck on this particular question...

I've attached an image of the problem[image] since I am not well versed in typing math equations.

I'm assuming that I will need to use the sum and difference identity.. but I am not entirely sure where it fits in. Any advice or recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Would I consider (u,v) = as polar coordinates (r,theta?

Answer (score 0):

If you replace $U$ by $x$ and $V$ by $y$, it will be

$\sqrt{U^2+V^2}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r$ (radius of the circle or amplitude of oscillation)

From math text, it is evident that the principal period of sinusoidal functions is $[0,2\pi)$.

Also $\sqrt{U^2+V^2}\geq U$ and $V$ so $-1\leq cos(angle)\leq1$

$F(\alpha)=\sqrt{U^2+V^2}cos(\alpha-\phi)=\sqrt{U^2+V^2}(cos\alpha cos\phi+sin\alpha sin\phi)=U cos\alpha +V sin\alpha$
(work backward)

Question is ambiguous. I don't have the privilege to comment and hence the answer.